# Download big files with QNetworkreply::readAll freeze for a few seconds

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtnetwork

I used example like doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

I create a `startDownload`:

```
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(startDownload(bool)));
```

In `startDownload(bool)` I put this:

```
file = new QFile("C:/foo/bar/bigfile.7z");
file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://localhost/bigfile.7z"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);

connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
```

In `slotReadyRead` I put this:

```
file->write(reply->readAll());
```

But when the download arrives at the end there is a small freezing 2 seconds and then returns to normal and the download is complete. This problem only occurs if the file I'm trying to transfer is large.

Comment: I tried to write a [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/et94k1Uk) for your issue. I calculated the time for every `file->write(reply->readAll())` call, most of the calls took 0 ms, the last call (at the end of the download) did not have a significant difference as you describe (I tried the code with a local file on my network that was about 1GB of size). Maybe it is another thing in your code that makes things slow? try to measure function calls duration to make sure it is really this call that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Mike the problem only occurs in GUI applications, for example with `QMainWindow`

Comment: The problem occurs in the GUI because a callback took *much* amount of time to finish and return back to the event loop. In my test, I am just measuring the amount of time spent in the `file->write(reply->readAll());` to make sure it really takes 2 seconds at the end of the download. But it turned out that it doesn't really take that long, is the output different at yours?

Comment: @Mike 18mb => https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSU2n.png in online server, 300mb in localhost => https://i.stack.imgur.com/m58Wn.png I think the problem varies according to the network.

Comment: @Mike I used `setReadBufferSize` and solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: How did that affect time spent in the `reply->readAll()` call? would you please elaborate on that in an answer and mark it as the solution to your problem?

Comment: @Mike Yes, see without setReadBufferSize => https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxhdH.png, with setReadBufferSize => https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMZQQ.png I'm doing some tests and will prepare a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried use @Mike code, I noticed that the data read in `readyRead` final are much higher than the previous which makes it slow to write in file:

[image: without setReadBufferSize]

The last two readings are:

1. 46080000 bytes - takes ~1.6 seconds to write.
2. 227323951 bytes - takes ~2.7 seconds to write.

> It varies according to the network type and speed, allowing the buffer to be great or not.

In GUI applications cause a sense of "freeze" for ~4 secs.

For limite buffer I used [`QNetworkReply::setReadBufferSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#setReadBufferSize), see the difference:

[image: with setReadBufferSize]

The reading was in 1048576 bytes - takes between 2 and 10 msecs to write.

Comment: @KubaOber I understand, but it was the only thing that worked, I followed the guidance of `@ddriver`, you could show me a better way?

Comment: You're leaking the instance of the network access manager. Since a download worker always needs the network access manager, you can add it as a member and hold it by value, there's no need to recreate it every time `process()` gets invoked.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. `QIODevice::readAll()` will block the thread until the download completes. It's possible `QFile::write()` may block as well depending on disk speed and caching policy. The `readAll()` method may also consume quite a bit of RAM if the file is large enough.

The simplest solution is to download the file in smaller chunks using `read()` instead of `readAll()`.

Now that said, there's no easy way to find the perfect buffer size to read from the network and write to the disk; it's going to depend on how the network connection responds vs. the disk write speed.

Comment: It's make sense, can provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: Or if you want to use the blocking api, don't block the main thread - use a worker thread.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks, but I tried using a thread, and had even made another question about it, what I got was several close votes and downvotes and a lot of reclameções in comments that made no sense, I deleted the question.

Comment: It was probably a duplicate, there are scores of questions on how to use worker threads, just use the search box.

Comment: @ddriver I found several unanswered or vague answers or pyqt4 (I do not understand anything PyQt4). You can show me some link with an answer that works. Thanks

Comment: @ddriver I'm looking for and all questions that I do not talk about the subject and examples in responses look like my code, ie I can not find any examples of how to solve this. Would you help me?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Comment: @ddriver ok I understand, I'll have to myself to study, understand and alternative technologies, I thought that here was a site to ask questions, but I see that in certain site tags have a need for culture, ie if you are new to technology or will ask the site. I thought the site to professionals, intermediate and beginners. But now I understand that only intermediate and professionals may have questions. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No, Stack Overflow is absolutely intended for beginners. Between my answer and ddriver's comments you have two possible approaches here; either should be fine. That said, it's starting to sound like you want someone to write code for you for free rather than answer your question.

Comment: @MrEricSir You are interpret really bad. I understand a little of the community, and other site of community I help enough: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=topactivity I'm talking about one thing and people are understanding each other. Unfortunately the problem is "communication".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - it is your English that's quite bad. This site is in English, so you need to be proficient at the language in order to be able to use the site. The documentation for QThread I linked contains everything you need.

Comment: @ddriver that's what I'm talking about, the answers here are basically: *"see the documentation"*, if so it is best to ask no one else on the site, only if a professional question. I even found nothing on Stack Overflow, the one who was found PyQT4... please do not get me wrong and I'm sorry the bad English, I was so upset that I spent writing too fast. See you.

Comment: You **must** read the documentation before you ask. That's the whole point of having documentation. You must only ask questions on topics that are more complex or not covered, or if you face a problem. This site is not about helping people too lazy to read the documentation. Many people don't even bother reading, don't even bother searching, instead ask directly. That's just being lazy. It should not be rewarded. It won't help you to get better, it will make you more lazy.

Comment: It is not a complex thing, put the download code in a QObject, create the object and a thread, move the object to a thread, then its functions will execute in that thread. Use a signal to queue a download, use a signal when the download is completed. That's simple event driven asynchronous programming. If you encounter a specific problem and get stuck, they ask a question, but only after you search. And don't take downvotes personally, they are not personal, it just means your question is not up to the standards of the community. But sometimes it is just "monkey see monkey do" ;)

Comment: [`readAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) is documented to return *remaining* data from the device. It does **not** block the thread. see its [implementation](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qiodevice.cpp?h=5.7#n1200), it is just about calling [`read()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read) to fill an array.

Comment: All of the blocking functions has their names starting with `waitFor...()`, [`waitForBytesWritten()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten)/[`waitForReadyRead()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead)/...

Comment: @Mike Good point! Feel free to post an answer with that info, or edit mine (I've changed it to a "Community Wiki")